# Views result group by date with count of a month results

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-views

I have an article listing section in a drupal 7 website made by Drupal views module, I arrange those article according to the group of the month but I am trying to put count the result of each month with month heading

See this:

[image: now getting]

Expecting this:

[image]

Thanks

Comment: Use hooks from views to alter your display : https://api.drupal.org/api/views/views.api.php/function/hook_views_pre_render/7.x-3.x

Comment: Exporting the View and posting the code here might be helpful in getting a case specific answer...